# How to listen to the events inside an object?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to listen to a click event and give the output accordingly.

However, I am a bit confuse on adding events inside an object.

I tried this.

```
var object1 = {
    getVariables: {
        button1: document.getElementById('button');
    },
    eventHandler: {
        getVariables.button1.addEventListener('click', this.alertSomething);
    },
    alertSomething: function() {
        alert('Cool');
    }
};
```

Is this a correct way to listen to the events? If not, please help me correct it.

Comment: If you want to do OOP in JavaScript, [maybe look into classes?](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes)

Comment: Also, writing comments begging for an answer won't get you a faster answer, just a small tip 

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to save the reference to the variable somewhere in the object - and for the object to reference itself to achieve that, it'll have to use `this` somehow. (well, you could also pass in the whole object as a separate argument, but that's kinda odd and not often done)

It's somewhat tricky because when calling `object1.getVariables.button1`, the context of `this` is the object referenced by the `getVariables` property, but you likely want to put the information into somewhere more appropriate within `object1` itself, not within `getVariables`. Let's store the variables in a `storedVariables` property.

We want the functions to be called with a reference to the outer object, not the `getVariables` or `addEventHandler` property, so we have to use `call` to pass a custom `this` to the functions:

```js
const button = document.getElementById('button');
const object1 = {
  storedVariables: {},
  getVariables: {
    button1: function() { this.storedVariables.button1 = document.getElementById('button') },
  },
  addEventHandler: {
    button1: function() { this.storedVariables.button1.addEventListener('click', this.alertSomething); },
  },
  alertSomething: function() {
    alert('Cool');
  }
};

object1.getVariables.button1.call(object1);
object1.addEventHandler.button1.call(object1);
```

```html
<div id="button">
some button
</div>
```

It would be notably less convoluted if there was a method such as `getButton1` directly on `object1` (and the same for `addEventHandler`), that way they could be called normally without having to customize their `this`.

Answer (score 0):

Just bind `object1` object to `this` variable.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<div id="button1">
Button-1
</div>

<script>
var object1 = {

    button1: document.getElementById('button1'),

    eventHandler: function() { 
  this.button1.addEventListener('click', this.alertSomething);
    },

    alertSomething: function() {
        alert('Cool');
    }

};

object1.eventHandler.call(object1);

</script>

</body>
</html>
```